# How to create C# Bitmap supporting PropertyItems from existing Image (from Camera)

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I am creating an C# Image from a camera. I want to create an image that supports PropertyItems from this image so that I can include audit-level details in the meta-data.

The Image created by the camera does not support PropertyItems, and so I want to create one that does from the existing image. Ideally it should be lossless, and fast.

Examples I have seen that create images that support these meta-data attributes are generated by reading the image from a file, and not from an in-memory already-existing image.

Any recommendations for this?

Note that I am avoiding using a containing class, or derived Image class for reasons of minimal integration issues.

Comment: I suggest finding some image that has all the PropertyItems you need and then copy the camara's image's pixels over to it and setting the items to their new values and sving under a new name..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "creating an C# Image from a camera" you mean "loading a JPEG image created by a camera into a C# Image object"?

The [PropertyItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.propertyitems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property of an Image object allows you to do this, regardless of whether your Camera populates such data itself or not.  If you open the (JPEG) image, set properties and save back.  If you don't edit the image bitmap itself, I believe it will be saved in the same (compressed) format.

Comment: The question really was how to add new PropertyItems.

Comment: Hey Chris,
Actually the image only exists at present as an Image, and not a specific file format. This is actually the cause of the issue. If I had it as a JPEG, then my path forward would be easy.
However, I do not want to incur a large penalty of producing a JPEG from the base image if I do not have to.